# Validation.ErorrTemplate dynamic change from viewModel in Xaml (Wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Is there a way to change the Validation.ErrorTemplate from viewModel ,based on property Error Type in mvvm style with IDataErrorInfo.

Eg. I have a property with two different validation templates , in one i display in a way and the another in another way based on the property if required  show a choosed template, if exceeds choosed the second one.

Thanks in advance
Ben

Comment: you mean, you need to change the Control Validation Template based on Peoperty Value?

Comment: yes somethink like that

Answer (score 0):

use this in your resource

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ct1">
    <!--Your First Template-->
</ControlTemplate>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ct2">
    <!--Your Second Template-->
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourProperty}" Value="yourValue1">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ct1}"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourProperty}" Value="yourValue2">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ct2}"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Safi is not what i what .I need a general aproach. when the my (Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent we retrive the error message , i need somehow to retrieve the errorMessageType (which could be an enum value) which i can switch the dataTemplate (the enum should be required, warning, range, )

Comment: and of course i dont want to specify in the dataTrigger the binding for a property